# I have uploaded thousands of files in the uploads folder via FTP and I want to register them into the database without any plugin

Tags: database, uploads, media, ftp

I have uploaded thousands of files in the uploads folder via FTP and I want to register them into the database without any plugin because plugin takes so much time. Is there any way to register them manually in the database via (any SQL query or any code)?

Comment: "because plugin takes so much time" - you mean you've got a plugin that will do this, but it's too slow? Are they images? By default WordPress will generate different scaled versions of images: is that's what's taking the time?

Comment: You can use [wp-cli's wp media import](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/import/) but it'd probably do the image resizes too and take just as long.

Comment: Yes I tried different plugins, and yes they are the images

Comment: There's probably a way to turn off all of the image sizes temporarily, e.g. a mu-plugin with an after_setup_theme hook or an init hook that calls remove_image_size() on all the ones you don't want, then run a plugin or wp-cli to import the images, then remove the filter. But I can't dig out the details right now.